# For loop iteration continues instead of waiting for `async.parallel` to complete its execution first in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, async.js

I am using NodeJS(Express) and async plugin.

```
for (var j = 0; j < totalTests; j++) {

        var caseDetailID, test, testID, testCode, testName, testTemplate, testType, testArray;



        /**
         * use async to make sure that caseDetailId(by forcing to execute first) will be available for testCaseParamter creation
         */

        test = tests[j];
        testArray = test.split(' , ');

        testID = testArray[0];
        testCode = testArray[1];
        testName = testArray[2];
        testType = testArray[3];
        testTemplate = testArray[4];

        console.log("Inside test " + testID);

        async.parallel([

            next => {
                console.log("Inside TestCaseDetail before " + testID);
                TestCaseDetails.create({
                    'case_id': case_id,
                    'test_id': testID,
                    'test_code': testCode,
                    'test_name': testName,
                    'test_type': testType,
                    'created_by': req.user.id
                }).then(row => {
                    console.log("Inside TestCaseDetail after " + testID);
                    caseDetailID = row.id;
                    next();
                });
            }
        ], (err) => { 
});
```

I have two tests in `tests` array with `testIDs` as 6 and 7. The output of this code in the console is in the following sequence as

```
Inside test 6
Inside TestCaseDetail before 6
Inside test 7
Inside TestCaseDetail before 7
Inside TestCaseDetail after 7
Inside TestCaseDetail after 7
```

Here problem is that when sequelize query starts to run, `async.parallel` block terminates and for loop perform its iteration. Now for loop goes to `testID` 7 as a result `Inside TestCaseDetail after 6` statement does not print in the console instead `Inside test 7` statement print in the console.

Correct output should be as following

```
Inside test 6
Inside TestCaseDetail before 6
Inside TestCaseDetail after 6
Inside test 7
Inside TestCaseDetail before 7
Inside TestCaseDetail after 7
```

I had already tried `async.series` but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: try change `next();` with `return next();`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But this does not solve the problem and output is same as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I have no idea how `async.parallel` works, so I can't tell if there is something wrong with flow.

But I can suggest the way, that will solve your issue with simple `async/await`:

```
(async () => {
    for (var j = 1; j < totalTests; j++) {
        console.log("Inside test " + j);
        await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${j}`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log("Inside TestCaseDetail after " + j, response.json());
                return response
            });
    }
})();
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-loop)**

---

Your code should lool like this :

```
(async () => {
    for (var j = 0; j < totalTests; j++) {
            ...
            // async.parallel([             //<----- REMOVE
                // next => {                //<----- REMOVE
                    console.log("Inside TestCaseDetail before " + testID);
                    await TestCaseDetails.create({
                        'case_id': case_id,
                        'test_id': testID,
                        'test_code': testCode,
                        'test_name': testName,
                        'test_type': testType,
                        'created_by': req.user.id
                    }).then(row => {
                        console.log("Inside TestCaseDetail after " + testID);
                        caseDetailID = row.id;
                        // next();          //<----- REMOVE
                    });
                // }                        //<----- REMOVE
            // ], (err) => {                //<----- REMOVE
            // });                          //<----- REMOVE
    }
})();
```

Comment: I'm unaware of angular. Can you please explain this error `Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
ERROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch`

Comment: @MuhammadYasir, please check again.

Comment: It does not solve my problem when I write a sequelize statement next to await then the `.then` block code does not execute instead loop continue its iteration while ignoring `.then` block.

Comment: you need to write `await TestCaseDetails.create(` like this. , check the updated answer

Comment: Yes, it worked I was putting console statement after await. My bad.

Comment: Man you are great. It was such a huge headache for me.